# Cannot extractPrediction using caret in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm totally stucked on a random forest classification model since I cannot extract predictions. And I'm really out of clues since:

```
predict(forest.model1, titanic.final.test)
```

works like a charm, while

```
extractPrediction(list(forest.model1), testX=titanic.final.test[,-2], testY=titanic.final.test[,2])
```

which should be equivalent, gives me this error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : 
  variables in the training data missing in newdata
```

Here's my trainControl:

```
forest.fitControl <- trainControl( method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, 
summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, classProbs=TRUE,
returnData=TRUE, seeds=NULL, savePredictions=TRUE, returnResamp="all")
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Test and Train need to have the same structure (i.e. all the same columns).  So my only guess is that negating the second column is resulting in a different structure that the data used to train the model.  Hard to know without seeing the structire of the training vs. test data.frames.

Edit After Looking at Code:
Recreated this from your repo...  Sure it shouldn't be the first column you pull out for testX and use for testY.  Something like:

```
extractPrediction(list(forest.model1), testX=titanic.final.test[,-1], testY=titanic.final.test[,1])
```

Comment: You were absolutely right; it was just a column selection issue I was totally blinded of. So much often the easier explaination is the best one! Tnx allot!

Comment: Great!  And I just re-read everything and realized I was off base about what extractPrediction() was doing.  Same idea though that the column selection was off.

Comment: Unfortunately I talked too early. I double checked and train and test set have absolutely the same number of columns. I'm totally sure about that. But still get the same error...

Comment: same number and same names?  For predict to work the names need to be an exact match.

Comment: Follow up question as I am unfamiliar with `caret`, what does extractPrediction provide the predict on its own doesn't?

Comment: Better to talk viewing the code -> https://github.com/theclue/machine-lemming/blob/master/Titanic%20-%20Learning%20from%20Disaster/barebone-random-forest.R As far as I can see, colnames(titanic.final.train) == colnames(titanic.final.test). The really weird stuff is that predict(randomforest, newdata) won't work, while predict(train, newdata) (provided by caret) does...

Comment: Edited my original answer.  Based on a very quick review of the code, it now seems like you are pulling out column 2 and it should be column 1, instead.

Comment: I was aware of the index error and fixed it already, no effect. But I made a further step. Basically, I checked the final model dug by train(). And I saw that factor variables were decomposed by creating a set of dummy logical columns. Function predict() itself does the same transposing the test set before doing anything, but extractPrediction() doesn't. That's why the error. If I manually do this before the training phase, I can call extractPrediction. However I noticed a slight decrease in accuracy. So my question is: when using RF, factor variables decomposing could affect the performance?